# "Manage Categories" not found for attribute from Backend

Tags: template, controllers

I try open "Manage Categories" in backend page but I get error page:

```
There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 2089437909
```

I do not understand the issue, MySQL version I thought maybe creating error and I updated MySQL but problem has not changed. Is this a problem with the template i bought? Thank you so much

*PHP: 5.5.11 // 
MySQL: 5.6.27*

**2089437909 Report:**

```
a:5:{i:0;s:110:"Source model "porto/category_attribute_source_tab_mode" not found for attribute "sw_product_staticblock_tab_1"";i:1;s:4972:"#0 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "p...')
#1 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#3 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout))
#8 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#9 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#10 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout))
#11 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(82): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#12 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#13 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout))
#14 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#15 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#16 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(40): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#19 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#20 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#21 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks()
#22 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#23 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#24 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#25 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#26 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#27 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#28 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#29 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#30 /home/em2010w/public_html/magento2/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#31 {main}";s:3:"url";s:86:"/magento2/index.php/admin/catalog_category/index/key/c98d1a5373166dd14aaf794d4bef7910/";s:11:"script_name";s:19:"/magento2/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be installed custom theme in your setup. Check if you have below class exist in your module or not.

```
Porto_Category_Attribute_Source_Tab_Mode
```

your attribute `sw_product_staticblock_tab_1` using this class as source model and system not able to find this class that is why it is showing this error.